# Issue with TCPDF on iPad

Tags: ipad, tcpdf, fatal-error

I have a dynamically created PDF on a site that will not display on an iPad. It displays on computers and iPhones but not on the iPad. With error reporting on it gives the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng() in pdf/tcpdf.php on line 8194
```

This is a GD library function that loads fine on all other platforms, so why is there an issue on the iPad? Shouldn't this be handled by apache, if so how can I force it to load the lGD library? I am at a total loss for how to fix this! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up commenting out the line in question. Not truly an answer to the question but it works without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; the fact that you are using an iPad to access a PHP application should not affect what modules are loaded.

Please check that you are actually accessing the server you think you are, and the vhost that you think you are. It seems most likely to me that you are accessing for example, a development server on one device and a test server on another. It is possible, although unlikely, that the apache configuration or .htaccess files contain directives that will stop certain PHP flags from being set in given situations.

Please check the source code of your application for calls to the [dl method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php). It is possible that the application will check for the GD library and load it if it is not loaded by default in php.ini. A logic error could be preventing the method from being called.

Once you have confirmed this, you might be able to debug the issue by using [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/phpinfo). Drop this method in and see if you can notice a difference between PHP versions and loaded modules. There may be a clue in the output that could help you solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change Font , Just a shot in dark , i had same problem with safari and solved with changing font

For example

```
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 4, '', true);
```